# "xdmp:eval" throws "XDMP-ARG: -- vars is invalid" exception when "()" [empty sequence] is passed for an optional external parameter

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

Below is the sample code where `$p2` is an `optional external parameter` (i.e. with `? modifier`); the code gives `XDMP-ARG:  -- vars is invalid` exception when `empty sequence-()` is passed against `$p2`.

Tried it on `Marklogic 8 & 9`

```
let $query := 
"
declare variable $p1 as node()? external;
declare variable $p2 as node()? external;
(
if($p1) then xdmp:log('P1') else ()
,
if($p2) then xdmp:log('P2') else ()
)

"
let $p1 := <p></p>
let $p2 := ()
return 
xdmp:eval(
          $query,
          (xs:QName('p1'), $p1, xs:QName('p2'), $p2)
         )
```

I expected the code to run and print logs. 
Can I get some deep insights into how the exception occurred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass in vars as a Sequence of key,val,key,val it needs to be even (multiple of 2). You can't embed sequences like that, as nested sequences get flattened automatically in XQuery. Pass in your vars using a map:map:

```
map:new((
  map:entry("p1", $p1),
  map:entry("p2", $p2),
))
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

A less-clean alternatives is to use a special marker value to represent 'empty' instead of a literal empty sequence -- which as HTH says, is not preserved when passed IN another sequence (not only do sequences not 'nest' but empty sequences are not 'countable' or 'identifiable' values exactly -- don't know the precise term).

this should demonstrate:

```
  let $x := ( 1 , () , () , 2 )
```

$x is now a sequence of length 2 not 4,   empty sequences resolve to nothing and the containing sequence 'collapses' (removes the slot, not putting a kind of 'null' value in it)

So a approach in general can be used which you substitute a 'empty token' of some kind.
like

```
  declare variable $empty :=  <empty/>
```

(: ANY single value or node type will work that is type compatible with non-empty uses :)

Now

```
  let $x :=  (1,$empty,$empty,2)  (: sequence length 4 :)
```

and thus you can pass to eval() replacing () with $empty.
The called code needs a test against $empty as well

```
  if( $p1 != $empty ) then xdmp:log("P1 is" , $p1 )
```

This technique is used sometimes to create sparse tree structures like binary trees, red/black trees etc.

HTH's solution is better. (this just demonstrates an alternative to help understand the core issue better)

Comment: You can also wrap your sequences, rather than special casing empty sequence. I have done so in the past using elements (when passing in arguments with map:map was not an option yet), but nowadays you could also use other things, and of those I'd recommend `json:to-array`, which requires using `json:array-values` inside the eval query to unwrap your arguments.